# Xcode warning - variable was never mutated

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that this is newbie question but I can not find answer on stackoverflow or google.

I am starting writing project with Swift 3 language. Here is my model class:

```
class VKUserProfile: NSObject {
    var userId: NSNumber?
    var userName: String?
    var userEmail: String?
    var userMobilePhone: String?
    var userPictureUrl: URL?
}
```

Then I use it in another class:

```
private func convert(user: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> VKUserProfile {
    var currentUser: VKUserProfile = VKUserProfile()
    currentUser.userId = user["id"] as? NSNumber
    return currentUser
}
```

Xcode warns me on line "var currentUser: VKUserProfile = VKUserProfile()". Ok, but when I change it to "let currentUser: VKUserProfile = VKUserProfile()" - I can not set any properties (object is empty). So can someone describe me this process, why Xcode warns and how I can fix this.

UPDATE:
Here is screenshot of currentUser variable when currentUser is let:

[image: let]

And this is screenshot of currentUser variable when currentUser is var:

[image]
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use `let`. That solves your immediate issue. Now clarify what you mean by "I can not set any properties".

Comment: @rmaddy I mean that when I write "let currentUser: VKUserProfile = VKUserProfile()" and then set variables like "currentUser.userId = user["id"] as? NSNumber" my currentUser still empty. Variables not set. No any data stored in currentUser. I pass this object to my UIViewController and can not use it (because currentUser has no data).

Comment: Are you sure that `user` has a value for the given key and it the value is of the given type? You really need to [edit] your question to be about the problem with setting the properties and not the use of `let/var`.

Comment: Thanks for the screen snapshots, but the immediate problem isn't the `VKUserProfile` object, but rather the `user` dictionary. More than likely, `user` either does not have any value associated with the key `id` or the value associated with that key is not a `NSNumber`. Maybe it's a string. Show us what `user` looks like.

Comment: Your edit isn't what you needed to clarify. Show the contents of `user`.

Comment: @rmaddy user object has all needed values. When I user var for currentUser I receive full object which I need. But when I change currentUser to let - the object is empty

Comment: @Rob When I user var for currentUser I receive full object which I need. But when I change currentUser to let - the object is empty. On screenshot I just close ids and other data. If currentUser is var I receive complete object with id, name, email, phone etc. When I move to let - current user is empty

Comment: Could the problem be with Xcode showing the information? I bet when you use `let`, the data is actually there just like it is when you use `var`. Don't trust Xcode's debugger.

Comment: @rmaddy you are 100% right! I print "print(currentUser)" to check value and it is also empty (but has address). The same in debug window. But when I print "print(currentUser.userId)" - I got my id in console. Very strange Xcode behaviour. Thank you for this hint! Please add this as answer and I accept it.

Comment: When you `print(currentUser)`, it won't show the values of the properties. It only does so for `struct` types or where you've conformed to `CustomStringConvertible` protocol and implemented `description` property to show you the values of the properties.

Comment: @Rob Actually, it's not the use of `print` as shown by the screen captures in the question. Xcode's debugger isn't showing the values for `currentUser` after being changed to `let`.

Comment: I understand that. My point was merely that with a custom `class` type, you can't just `print` the object and expect to see the values, either. You'll only see the address unless you conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: @Rob thank you for note this, I will try to provide extra log information for my classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that when you use:

```
var currentUser = VKUserProfile()
```

the rest of your code properly fills in `currentUser` and you can see the values when you print `currentUser`.

But using `var` gives a warning since you never actually reassign `currentUser`.

So you rightfully change `var` to `let` and make no other changes. But now when you print `currentUser`, you don't see the same output as you did when you use `var` as shown in the screenshots you posted in your question.

It seems this is a problem with Xcode's debugger.

Printing individual properties of `currentUser` shows the expected output.

So in the end, this is nothing but a bug in Xcode's debugger. Your code is fine even after changing `var` to `let`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!